# Is there a way to put a floating action button on the bottom corner of an image view?

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout, and I'd like to have a floating action button sit on top of an image button on its bottom right corner. I'm currently using a constraint layout. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

Here's my current implementation:

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/option1_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/option1_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/option1_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/option1_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/option1_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/option1_button"
                android:src="@drawable/gallery"
                app:fabSize="mini"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you will just constraint you floating button to the to top your image view (constraint top and bottom) and do the same for the horizontal contains (they should be to the right of the view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@color/buttonColor"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Editing according to the comment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/option1_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="642dp"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/option1_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gallery"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />



<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That didn't really change anything when I made those changes. Added my current implementation to the question. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you check my updated answer now? I removed some attributes, tell me if its working now.

Comment: I have these two elements inside of a vertical linear layout nested in a horizontal linear layout. Where should the guideline go?

Comment: Where should the guideline go?  put it anywhere you want, in my example, it is on 50% screen height but that was just an example  - if you want to change it feel free.

Comment: The app crashed after implementing this :(